# getting the value of selected dropdown, but not from the checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have the following scripts that work just fine when i use dropdown, but doesn't work when i use checkbox:

```
function update_number_of_adds_found(field_dropdown, selected_value) {
    selected_value = "";

    var addtypeid = $("#addtypeid").val(); // dropdown
    var ch67 = $("#67").is(':checked'); // checkbox
    //alert($("#67").val());
    alert("Hello");
    var selected_value = {
        addtypeid: addtypeid,
        isdamaged: isdamaged
    };
    var url = "<?php echo site_url('search/findNumberOfAdds'); ?>";
    $.post(url, selected_value, function(r) {
        if (r) {

            $('#totalNumOfAdds').empty();
            $("#totalNumOfAdds").append(r.result);
        } else {
            // alert(selected_value);
        }
    }, 'json')
}
```

Here is the html for the dropdown:

```
<select name="addtypeid" id="addtypeid" class="styled_select" onchange="update_number_of_adds_found($('#addtypeid'), this.value);">
```

and here is the code for the checkbox:

```
$msg = '"update_number_of_adds_found($('.$value['filterid'].'), this.value);"';
echo "<input type='checkbox' name='categoriesfilters[]' value='" .$value['filterid'] ."' class='zcheckbox' onclick='$msg'/>";
```

Alert hello is not called when i click on the checkbox, but it does when i change the dropdown.

Regards, John

Comment: could u jsfiddle it.Both the working and the not working one

Comment: If it's not called then either the function is not invoked or you have a runtime error. [Learn how to](http://www.creativebloq.com/javascript/javascript-debugging-beginners-3122820) [**debug** JavaScript](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging).

Comment: Both checkbox and dropdown have different behavior. You can check for onclick event instead

Comment: nothing in the console however. i have no idea how to make jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You enclosed the function call in double quotes. So in your onclick attribute. it will look like this `onclick='"update_number_of_adds_found($(someFilterId), this.value);"'

So when you click you are not running a function call rather you are just running a "string".

**Note** : when i mean running a "string" i mean it just gets stored in memory doesn't execute the string as a javascript code.

This should solve the issue

```
 $msg = 'update_number_of_adds_found($("'.$value['filterid'].'"), this.value);';
```

Comment: works like a charm now. thanks. alert is now invoked.

Comment: do you have any idea why  var ch67 = $("#67").val(); when alerted returns undefined?

Comment: can you post the html for the element with id `67`?

Comment: that is possible only when there is no element with id '67'